# What is the title of Darwin's paper on cellular structure?

Tags: cell-biology

I read somewhere that Darwin wrote a paper that dealt with cellular structure, but I've been unable to find the title or contents of the paper because Darwin wrote such a volume of material. What is the title of this paper or papers?

A [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=darwin+cell+structure&oq=darwin+cell+structure&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.945.4858.0.5009.31.17.5.6.7.2.229.1722.10j6j1.17.0.les%3B..1.0...1c.1.aF7QyE_Dwb4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=86c0df5ee6ec5cdc&biw=1280&bih=931) does not turn up any helpful results, and a similar search in [google scholar](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=darwin+cell+structure&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C14&as_sdtp=) yields equally ambiguous results (at least to me, since I do not have a background in biology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Darwin had written lots of papers which dealt with *fertilization* (which involves single cells), as he primarily dealt with the reproduction, continuation and thus evolution of a species, but these did not deal with cell biology specifically.

After a closer look at the [complete list of all his publications](http://darwin-online.org.uk/contents.html), I found that he did have two cell-related publishings, specifically about **the size of cells**, one entitled [Bees in Jamaica increase the size and substance of their cells](http://darwin-online.org.uk/converted/pdf/1862_jamaica_F1826_001.pdf), and the other, [Bee-cells in Jamaica not larger than in England](http://darwin-online.org.uk/converted/pdf/1862_beecells_F1824_001.pdf), in which he retracts the statement he had made in the previous article.

Ultimately, to answer your question, it seems as though none of his works dealt with *cellular structures*.

---

### References

- **Charles Darwin**. *"Bees in Jamaica increase the size and substance of their cells".* Journal of Horticulture (15 July): 305.
- **Charles Darwin**. *"Bee-cells in Jamaica not larger than in England."* Journal of Horticulture (22 July): 323.